# How do we get Rocket Pass 5?

Tags: rocket-league

I am a long-time Rocket League fan. I love the game. However, I do not know how we are supposed to get Rocket Pass 5's Premium Tiers. This is because 10 Keys have been used to unlock Rocket Passes 1-4. However, the Blueprint Update, which will change the key and crate systems, comes with Rocket Pass 5. How do I get this?

Comment: Warning: if you have existing credits, and buy more to purchase the rocket pass thinking that will not use your "non cooldown" credits, that won't happen. If you purchase new credits, **all** existing credits will be placed in a 3 day cooldown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys have been turned into credits. You get [between 100 to 130 credits per key](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/e531yp/psa_keystocredits_conversion_change/), depending on how many keys you have.

The new Rocket Pass costs 1000 credits.

Comment: Which means that, if you're lucky as (censored), You could Get the Rocket Pass  with only 8 keys having been in your inventory prior to Rocket Pass 5.

Comment: @MCAydenBird: Yep! Except it's not based on luck, it's based on how many keys you had in your inventory If you had over 50 keys, it will only cost 8.